# Final static variables operations, compile or runtime?

Tags: java

Do final static variables operations happen in run-time or compile time ? For example:

```
public static final int ID_1 = 1;
public static final int ID_2 = 2;

public static int test(){
    return ID_1 + ID_2; // Does this addition execute in compile or runtime ?
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a hint here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

It says:

> If a primitive type or a string is defined as a constant and the value is known at compile time, the compiler replaces the constant name everywhere in the code with its value.

So once that is done and you end up with `1 + 2` in the method, it would be logical for that to be optimized as well and just use the `3` at compile time.

To prove it in practice, you can compile your code and then decompile it to see what's going on.

I tried with JD-GUI and this is what I got when decompiling your code:

```
    public class TestCompileOrRuntime
    {
      public static final int ID_1 = 1;
      public static final int ID_2 = 2;

      public static int test()
      {
        return 3;
      }
    }
```

So it looks in this case the compiler is solving the operation in compile time.

Comment: You think your test method is reliable ? I would much rather find an answer in the java docs, but no similar results seem to appear on google

Comment: Why would it not be reliable? The compiled code has the "3" in there, so the calculation happened when compiling the file...

Comment: Yea, @Shiro, why isn't it reliable?

Comment: @Jeremy I didn't say it is not reliable, I simply asked how reliable is this, since I have no idea what JD-GUI could be doing behind the scenes.

Comment: @shiro: JD-GUI it's supposed to just decompile. Anyway, I included a link to a documentation that might explain that in a more "official" way. Check the edit in my answer.

Comment: if I were to write `final int twoHundred 200` and use it later in a for loop, would the final variable be initialized every loop cycle or will the compiler optimize it out? Because checkstyle requires magic numbers to be factored out into finals. Will the compiler inline the variables anyway as if I ignored the checkstyle warning, thus not impacting performance?

Answer (score 2):

It's a *compile time* operation (I get a method local `iconst_3` below). We can directly examine the generated bytecode with `javap -v`. I created a class `Main` like,

```
package com.stackoverflow;

public class Main {
    public static final int ID_1 = 1;
    public static final int ID_2 = 2;

    public static int test() {
        return ID_1 + ID_2; // <-- Compile time.
    }
}
```

and then ran `javap -v` to get

```
Classfile /home/efrisch/workspace/StackOverflow/bin/com/stackoverflow/Main.class
  Last modified Aug 22, 2015; size 410 bytes
  MD5 checksum 6ba30603e8f16cbebc681a84061d38c3
  Compiled from "Main.java"
public class com.stackoverflow.Main
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Class              #2             // com/stackoverflow/Main
   #2 = Utf8               com/stackoverflow/Main
   #3 = Class              #4             // java/lang/Object
   #4 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
   #5 = Utf8               ID_1
   #6 = Utf8               I
   #7 = Utf8               ConstantValue
   #8 = Integer            1
   #9 = Utf8               ID_2
  #10 = Integer            2
  #11 = Utf8               <init>
  #12 = Utf8               ()V
  #13 = Utf8               Code
  #14 = Methodref          #3.#15         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
  #15 = NameAndType        #11:#12        // "<init>":()V
  #16 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #17 = Utf8               LocalVariableTable
  #18 = Utf8               this
  #19 = Utf8               Lcom/stackoverflow/Main;
  #20 = Utf8               test
  #21 = Utf8               ()I
  #22 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #23 = Utf8               Main.java
{
  public static final int ID_1;
    descriptor: I
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_FINAL
    ConstantValue: int 1

  public static final int ID_2;
    descriptor: I
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_FINAL
    ConstantValue: int 2

  public com.stackoverflow.Main();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #14                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 4: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
            0       5     0  this   Lcom/stackoverflow/Main;

  public static int test();
    descriptor: ()I
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=0, args_size=0
         0: iconst_3
         1: ireturn
      LineNumberTable:
        line 9: 0
      LocalVariableTable:
        Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
}
SourceFile: "Main.java"
```

Comment: What will happen if you initialize one of those variables with the result of a `static` method?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza You might want to check this [example](https://github.com/tonymorris/java-trivia/blob/master/src/Constants.java) for testing the compiler behavior due to different initialization styles (but the case with the `static` method is missing).